# How to make two threads wait then run, given that they use a BlockedQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm writing an app that uses producer and consumer threads. I need to start, pause and cancel, the threads. The producer and consumer share a `BlockedQueue`. I have a toggle button to pause the threads and make them wait and then to run them again. In the threads there are flags to indicate if the threads are waiting or running. However if the BlockedQueue is blocking somewhere in the thread, then the thread can't reach to check if the thread should wait or keep running. How can I solve this please?

Here's my current code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GUIController implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>(10);
    private final List<Integer> holder = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    private volatile ApplicationState appState = ApplicationState.CLEAN;
    private FakeProducer fakeProducer = new FakeProducer("FakeProducer");
    private FakeConsumer fakeConsumer = new FakeConsumer();

    //GUI stuff
    static JToggleButton startBtn;
    //static JToggleButton pauseBtn;
    static JButton stopBtn;
    static JButton showBtn;

    private enum ApplicationState {
        CLEAN, RUN, PAUSE
    }

    private enum ThreadState {
        RUNNING, WAITING
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        GUIController guiController = new GUIController();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Concurrency");
        frame.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(400, 200));
        frame.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        startBtn = new JToggleButton("Start");
        startBtn.addItemListener(guiController);

        stopBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
        stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
        stopBtn.setActionCommand("Cancel");
        stopBtn.addActionListener(guiController);

        showBtn = new JButton("Show");
        showBtn.setActionCommand("Show");
        showBtn.addActionListener(guiController);

        frame.getContentPane().add(startBtn);
        frame.getContentPane().add(stopBtn);
        frame.getContentPane().add(showBtn);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        System.out.println(command + " is clicked");

        if ( command.equals("Cancel") ) {
            startBtn.setText("Start");
            appState = ApplicationState.CLEAN;

            synchronized (fakeProducer) {
                fakeProducer.notify();
            }

            synchronized (fakeConsumer) {
                fakeConsumer.notify();
            }

            holder.clear();
            executor.shutdown();
        }
        else if ( command.equals("Show") ) {
            for ( int i : holder ) {
                System.out.println("[" + i + "]");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    class FakeProducer implements Runnable {

        private String name;
        public ThreadState state;

        public FakeProducer(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            state = ThreadState.RUNNING;
            List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            for ( int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++ ) {
                list.add(i);
            }

            /**
             * While the application state is run, then keep running.
             * But if the state is put to be paused, then the thread waits.
             * I want to start running again after putting the application to pause.
             * When I click Cancel, then the application stop the thread. Then I start as clean.
             */

            for ( int i : list ) {
                if ( appState == ApplicationState.RUN ) {
                    try {
                        //This line blocks the app if there is no
                        //space in the queue, so it 
                        //will never reach appState=Pause
                        queue.put(i);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else if (appState == ApplicationState.PAUSE) {
                    try {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            state = ThreadState.WAITING;
                            wait();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        //This condition is to not to miss the i_th item when the state
                        //was PAUSE
                        if ( appState == ApplicationState.RUN ) {
                            try {
                                queue.put(i);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if ( appState == ApplicationState.CLEAN ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            //This is to let the rest of the app know that the list is finished
            //appState = ApplicationState.CLEAN;    
        }

    }

    class FakeConsumer implements Runnable {
        public ThreadState state;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            state = ThreadState.RUNNING;
            while( (appState == ApplicationState.RUN) || (appState == ApplicationState.PAUSE) ) {
                if ( appState == ApplicationState.RUN ) {
                    try {
                        //If this thing is blocking then it won't see anything i.e
                        //it won't check appState if Pause
                        //holder.add( queue.take() );
                        int value = queue.remove();
                        holder.add(value);

                    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else if (appState == ApplicationState.PAUSE) {
                    try {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            state = ThreadState.WAITING;
                            wait();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if ( e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED ) {

            if ( appState == ApplicationState.CLEAN ) {
                System.out.println("Start");
                startBtn.setText("Pause");
                appState = ApplicationState.RUN;
                executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
                fakeProducer = new FakeProducer("FakeProducer");
                fakeConsumer = new FakeConsumer();
                executor.execute( fakeProducer );
                executor.execute( fakeConsumer );
                executor.shutdown();
                stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
            }
            //Now continue execution
            else if ( appState == ApplicationState.PAUSE ) {
                startBtn.setEnabled(false);

                System.out.println( fakeProducer.state  );
                System.out.println( fakeConsumer.state  );

                //Block the app until all threads are waiting
                while( fakeProducer.state == ThreadState.RUNNING | 
                        fakeConsumer.state == ThreadState.RUNNING ) {
                }

                /*
                 *Once they are really both are waiting, then push them to work again
                 */

                appState = ApplicationState.RUN;

                synchronized (fakeProducer) {
                    fakeProducer.state = ThreadState.RUNNING;
                    fakeProducer.notify();
                }

                synchronized (fakeConsumer) {
                    fakeConsumer.state = ThreadState.RUNNING;
                    fakeConsumer.notify();
                }

                startBtn.setText("Pause");
                stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
                startBtn.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Pause");
            startBtn.setText("Continue");
            appState = ApplicationState.PAUSE;
            stopBtn.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

}
```

If you have comments to enhance my code and make it more robust, please tell me!

Comment: You could interrupt the thread that is blocked in waiting put() when changing ThreadState to PAUSED ...

Answer (score -1):

Put something into the queue that tells them to exit.

Comment: I don't need poison pill here. I need to maintain *synchronized* states for the threads.

Comment: You said you did. You said you needed them to 'start, pause, and cancel'. You start them; the BlockingQueue itself provides the pausing; so the only issue left is the cancel, which is solved as above.